# Compare decimal strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, floating-point, numbers

I have an input of two strings, each of which representing a non-negative rational number in decimal format.

Given these two strings `x` and `y`, I would like to check if the numeric value represented by `x` is larger than the numeric value represented by `y`.

These two values can be very large, as well as to extend to a very high precision (i.e., many digits after the decimal-point).

As such, I cannot rely on `Number(x) > Number(y)` to do the job.

Instead, I have implemented the following function:

```
function isLarger(x, y) {
    const xParts = x.split(".").concat("");
    const yParts = y.split(".").concat("");
    xParts[0] = xParts[0].padStart(yParts[0].length, "0");
    yParts[0] = yParts[0].padStart(xParts[0].length, "0");
    xParts[1] = xParts[1].padEnd  (yParts[1].length, "0");
    yParts[1] = yParts[1].padEnd  (xParts[1].length, "0");
    return xParts.join("").localeCompare(yParts.join("")) == 1;
}
```

I have conducted extensive testing, by generating random input `x` and `y`, and comparing the result of `isLarger(x, y)` to the value of the expression `Number(x) > Number(y)`.

Of course, for the reasons mentioned above, I cannot rely on the value of the expression `Number(x) > Number(y)` to be correct for every possible input `x` and `y`.

So I would like some kind of feedback on the function above:

- Does it have any caveats in it?
- Is there perhaps a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: do you have some examples with results?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I have called many times it with both `x` and `y` set to `(Math.random() * 1000000).toString()`. Then compared its output with `Number(x) > Number(y)`. The results always seem to hold, but like I said - how can I trust `Number(x) > Number(y)`? Also, as you can see, my generated input does not include extremely large values.

Comment: I don't see any immediate caveats. There are some libraries out there to work with big decimals, like [this one](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/), but no idea how they compare in performance to your implementation.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Thanks. I was trying to avoid using `BigNumber.js` and `Decimal.js`, and keep it in "native" JS.

Comment: You could definitely optimize your implementation a little. For example, just comparing the lengths of the integral parts would probably eliminate a lot of the later padding and string comparisons.

Comment: ^ and you could omit the end padding. you could add a dot to the end of the string before splitting. btw do you something like `.3`? or is in this case a leading zero mandantory?

Comment: @NinaScholz: No, I am not expecting an input with no integral part left of the dot. Regarding the "add a dot to the end of the string before splitting" suggestion - I am adding an empty string after splitting, which I believe to be achieving the same effect.

Comment: @goodvibration Are numbers padded with leading zeros (eg. `001` instead of simple `1` considered a valid input? And how about thousand separators (such as commas in English, eg. `1,000,000.00`)? I assume that these will never be included in the input?

Comment: You can test your test code by inserting deliberate bugs in `isLarger` and seeing if they are detected. For example, ignore the part after the decimal point.

Comment: @PetrSrníček: I don't receive such input, but I believe that it wouldn't impact the result even if I did, since my method adds leading zeros anyhow. There are no commas or anything. The input strings can be converted to `Number` (though the result might be inaccurate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any caveats in your solution, but the last line is unnecessarily complex. Instead of

`return xParts.join("").localeCompare(yParts.join("")) == 1;`

You could simply use this:

`return xParts.join("") > yParts.join("");`

### Simpler solution with some limitations on input values

If you can be absolutely sure that your input will never contain numbers with unecessary leading zeros (eg. `001` instead of `1`) or decimal numbers starting with a point (eg. `.1` instead of `0.1`) you can signficantly simplify the comparison by first comparing the number of digits in the integer parts.

More digits in the integer part means a greater number, less digits means a smaller number.

When the number of integer digits is the same, a simple string comparison is basically sufficient. Only one padding operation is necessary - `y` needs to be padded with trailing zeros in order not to get truthy result if `x` equals `y` but contains more trailing zeros (because `'211.00' > '211.0'` is `true`).

```
function isLarger(x, y) {
    const xIntLength = x.search(/\.|$/); /* Finds position of . or end of string */
    const yIntLength = y.search(/\.|$/); /* Finds position of . or end of string */
    /* Compare lengths of int part */
    if (xIntLength !== yIntLength) {
      return xIntLength > yIntLength;
    } else {
    /* Add decimal point to Y if not present and add  trailing zeros
       because otherwise eg. '2.00' > '2.0' would return true */
      const yWithDecimalPoint = y.includes('.') ? y : y + '.';
      const paddedY = yWithDecimalPoint.padEnd(x.length,'0');
      return x > paddedY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about `return xParts.join("") > yParts.join("");`?

Comment: @goodvibration Yes, I am sure about that. See [this description](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) of simple comparison of strings in JS. (Or see the [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) if you don't trust a random source.) `localeCompare` is intended for special locale-aware alphabetical comparison of strings (to make sure that eg. `á` comes before `b` even though its codePoint value does not).

Comment: @goodvibration I have edited my code to account for the possibilty of y not containing the decimal point. (My original code returned incorrect result for `x=20.1` and `y=20`, because y got padded to `2000` instead of `20.0` and `'.'` is smaller than `'0'`).

Comment: Thank you. I've adapted only your `xParts.join("") > yParts.join("")` suggestion, because if there are no caveats in my original code, then I'd like to keep it as simple as possible (on the expanse of performance if necessary). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a caveat about your testing method. I implemented it as far as I understood from the question and comments. To test the test method, I introduced a gross error in `isLarger`, completely ignoring the portion after the decimal point.

Even with such a gross error, I got 5 failures in 10,000,000 runs, equivalent to 0.5 failures per million runs.

I think you need a test method that puts in more cases where parts of the numbers match.

Here is my program:

```
function isLarger(x, y) {
    const xParts = x.split(".").concat("");
    const yParts = y.split(".").concat("");
    xParts[0] = xParts[0].padStart(yParts[0].length, "0");
    yParts[0] = yParts[0].padStart(xParts[0].length, "0");
    xParts[1] = xParts[1].padEnd(yParts[1].length, "0");
    yParts[1] = yParts[1].padEnd(xParts[1].length, "0");
    xParts[1] = "";
    yParts[1] = "";
    return xParts.join("").localeCompare(yParts.join("")) == 1;
}

function testIt(x, y) {
    const actual = isLarger(x, y);
    const expected = Number(x) > Number(y);
    if (actual != expected) {
        console.log("x=" + x + " y=" + y + " actual " + actual + " expected "
                + expected);
    }
}

function randAsString() {
    return (Math.random() * 1000000).toString();
}

testIt("3.3", "3.2");
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    testIt(randAsString(), randAsString());
}
```